# SpringBoot JPA MySQL Column names

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to access a simple MySQL Stored Procedure through SpringBoot.

Table

```
employee(empId int, empName varchar(100), empAddress varchar(1000), primary key (empId, empName))
```

Stored Procedure

```
PROCEDURE `get_Employee`(employeeId int)
BEGIN
    select empId,empName,empAddress from employee where empId = employeeId;
END
```

Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private int empId;
    private String empName;
    private String empAddress;

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }

    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getEmpAddress() {
        return empAddress;
    }

    public void setEmpAddress(String empAddress) {
        this.empAddress = empAddress;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Employee{");
        sb.append("empId=").append(empId);
        sb.append(", empName='").append(empName).append('\'');
        sb.append(", empAddress='").append(empAddress).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

SpringBoot Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JDBCApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JDBCApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        String sql = "SELECT empId,empName,empAddress FROM employee";
        List<Employee> employees = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(Employee.class));
        employees.forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println("-----------------");
        employees = employeeDAO.getEmployeeList(1004);
        employees.forEach(System.out::println);

    }
}
```

When I run the class I get an error that Column 'emp_Id' is not Found. Not sure how did it come up with this column name.

Also after the run, the Employee table ends up adding 3 new columns. A new column, each for an existing column but with '_' in it. like emp_Id, emp_Name, emp_Address. It ends becoming this

```
TABLE `employee` (
  `empId` int NOT NULL,
  `empName` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `empAddress` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_id` int NOT NULL,
  `emp_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emp_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`empId`,`empName`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

This is strange, never seen such scenario before. This is my first time trying MySQL DB. Is this normal? Also once I change my get_Employee SP to refer columns with '_', instead of my original columns, it works fine. Any thoughts on this? TIA

Answer (score 2):

You can explicitly declare what the column names should be with

```java
    @Id
    @Column( name="empId" )
    private int empId;
    @Column( name="empName" )
    private String empName;
    @Column( name="empAddress" )
    private String empAddress;
```

You could also [change the default naming strategy employed by Spring Boot](https://dev.to/aleksey/hibernate-naming-strategies-jpa-specification-vs-spring-boot-opinionation-m1c).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I could get over the problem by adding the @Column annotation.